# Radio Group and Shared user Default bind

Tags: cocoa

I have a preference panel with a radio group of 3 value, the `selected index` of this group is bind to `shared User Default` with:

**Control key:** `values`

**Model key Path:** `myoption`

If i launch my app with these bind settings it crash, i must specify:

**Value Transformer** `NSUnarchiveFromData`

This way launching from `defaults read com.mapp.identifier` i get a NSData description for "myoption" value.

Here my doubt:

Why i need to use NSArchive for selected index value ? i was pretty sure it's managed as an integer! But here i found that i have to store it as NSData.

Answer (score 0):

I usually bind to selected tag instead, manually setting tag values for the individual cells in the matrix that match either the indexes themselves or more significant values of my model.